# Программная настройка консоли

Tags: c#, консоль

Хочу сделать крошечный проект на консоли и тут возникает несколько вопросов:

1. можно ли задать текстовый режим без искажения по (X,Y);
2. задать разрешение консоли на определённое количество символов по  (X,Y);
3. запретить изменять размер;
4. сделать курсор невидимым;
5. изменить название с указанного пути на своё;
6. убрать полосу прокрутки;
7. разместить консоль по центру экрана?

В основном все предлагают ПКМ и менять всё в свойствах консоли, но это решение не устаивает.

Comment: не нужно вандализировать свои вопросы

Comment: Идёт жесточайшая борьба за сохранение качества вопросов))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Непонятно, что имеется в виду. Сделать знакоместо (размер символов) квадратным? Думаю, для это придётся менять шрифт.
2. 

```
Console.WindowHeight = 40;
Console.WindowWidth = 40;
```

3. Не думаю, что это возможно на чистом C#.
   Но можно с помощью функций WinAPI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792443/5045688
4. 

```
Console.CursorVisible = false;
```

5. 

```
Console.Title = "Название";
```

6. Задать размер буфера равным размеру окна:

```
Console.SetBufferSize(40, 40);
```

Comment: Отлично всё получилось кроме 3.п; и ещё вопрос: как разместить консоль по центру экрана?

Comment: @damp.ali - Пункт 3: просто скопировать код по ссылке! Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V - что может быть проще? / Не спрашивайте в комментариях! Редактируйте вопрос или создавайте новую тему.

Comment: да, спасибо. копипаст могучая вещь. добавил 7.п в вопрос

Comment: @damp.ali не надо до бесконечности редактировать вопрос. Если у вас новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно. Вообще консоль сама по себе не предназначена для того что вы пытаетесь с ней сделать. Если вам нужен полный контроль над окном, создайте десктопное приложение, например Windows Forms или WPF и вытворяйте с окном что угодно не прибегая к сложным WinAPI вызовам. Кстати, расположение окна по центру экрана не является удобным. Например у меня 2 монитора, в этом случае центр - это где? Центр какого монитора, или центр это на стыке мониторов? Подумайте хорошо, задача простая, условия продумайте.

Comment: я пытаюсь сделать то что не предназначено намеренно, именно такая задача стоит передо мной. по поводу центрирования подумайте вот о чём - это больше надо на момент проектирования проекта, вызывая его тысячи раз что бы не перетаскивать окно для просмотра результата от куда то сверху-слева - это не просто неудобно, это невыносимо и ломает глаза... и извините за неловкое обращение с ресурсом.

Comment: @damp.ali всё просто - задайте новый вопрос, изложите конкретно, что и зачем нужно. А вообще, вот наверное ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/67010648/12888024